# iphone development: communicating with server and push to anotherview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, connection

Well lets say I have two viewcontrollers "ViewControllerA" and "ViewControllerB". What I am doing is when a button pressed in the viewControllerA, my local server returns me a value and I store it in a variable "user". After that I pass this variable to viewControllerB.

Actually I can do both processes successfully but not at the same time. I mean I can receive the response from the server and store it in a string variable. I do it by using the delegate method:

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

So there is no problem at this side.

On the other hand I can also pass a variable to viewControllerB from viewControllerA by using:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"vcSegue"]){
        ViewControllerB *controller = (ViewControllerB *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.stringVariable = @"content of the string";
    }
}
```

The think is when I want to pass the string variable which I have from the server to the viewControllerB I face with a problem that the variable comes null. so how can I control the push action? because what i understand is `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` should work after the `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` I mean, I should have the response from the server successfully, then push action should be performed but I cant figure out how to do. thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider allowing ViewController B to load it's own detail data by perhaps passing an ID and letting it make it's own call. You could display a progress HUD while the data is being loaded.

If you wanted to pass an identifier you could do so with a custom init function:

```
- (id)initWithEvent: (NSString *) identifier
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        theIdentifier = identifier;                
     }
      return self;
}
```